# Tabela não recarrega após excluir uma linha

Tags: angular, typescript

Opa devs tranquilo? seguinte, estou fazendo um crud para a empresa onde trabalho, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que ela atualize automaticamente após eu deletar a linha, sendo necessário eu dar refresh manualmente no navegador, rodei um `alert();` na função `reloadTable()` só para testar e ver se realmente ele estava funcionando e sim ele está, o alert aparece porém mesmo assim ele não executa a operação.. o que eu posso ter errado ai? Ainda estou iniciando com o Angular. Segue meu código abaixo:

```
 delete(row){
    console.log(row);
    this.cartService.delete(row.Id)
    .then(data => this.reloadTable(true));
  }

  reloadTable(reload: boolean = false){
    alert("test");
    this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { reload } });
  }
```

Comment: o próprio angular já se ocupa de atualizar a tabela quando você deleta uma linha. No entanto, aparentemente você está deletando a linha apenas no backend. Uma opção é na função "reloadTable" você buscar no backend os valores atualizados após a exclusão. Outra opção é no "delete(row)" você remover o valor da variável que está apresentada na tabela também

Comment: A lista de onde você vai remover está no mesmo component?

Comment: @adventistaam sim ela está no mesmo component

Comment: @brenodiogo no caso como eu faria para buscar esses dados no backend utilizando o angular?

Comment: Olha eu tentei utilizando o `this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { reload } });` e passei no `navigate` a rota para o link da tabela ele até atuliza, mas apenas a ultima linha e de vez em quando ainda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utilizei uma função a qual eu não tinha visto que eu já tinha no meu código, meu parceiro de equipe me ajudou. Utilizei a seguinte solução:

```
async getAll() {
    this.rows$ = await this.cartService.getAll().toPromise();
  }

  delete(row){
    console.log(row);
    this.cartService.delete(row.Id)
    .then(data => this.getAll());
  }
```

Apaguei a função `reloadTable()` já que não havia necessidade utiliza-la e usei a `getAll()` onde ela puxa as linhas da tabela. Agora está tudo certo, Obrigado a todos! <3